# SSIS - transform 2 records from table A to 1 record in table B

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have following data in employee Table A:

```
ID  | emp | City_Type  | City
1   | 101 | Z          | Tokyo
2   | 101 | Y          | New York
```

`City_Type` can either be Y or Z. Y being the city this person was born in, Z is the city he/she is living now. 
I need to put these together in a table 'B' which look like the folowing:

```
ID  | emp | Current_City  | Birth_City
```

So in the end, Table B must be filled like this:

```
ID  | emp | Current_City  | Birth_City
1   | 101 | Tokyo         | New York
```

(in some cases, one of the 2 can be empty/null)

Any suggestions on how to do this? I haven't been able to found much information on this myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this exercise (using sql-server) with [PIVOT TABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx):

```
select emp, Z 'Current_City'   , Y 'Birth_City' from 
(
  select  emp,City_Type, City from  TABLE__A

) x
pivot
(
max(City) FOR City_Type in (Z,Y)
) AS PivotTable
```

below the result achieved, with an example of a NULL value for the field Current_City

```
emp Current_City    Birth_City
101 Tokyo           New York
102 NULL            London
```

I omitted ID, it is not clear from the request if and what needs to be added ( minimum, maximum on emp , or a new calculated or due to the INSERT in TABLE__B)

This previous query can be used to insert into TABLE__B

```
INSERT INTO [TABLE__B]
           ([emp]
           ,[Current_City]
           ,[Birth_City])
...
```

Answer (score 1):

First create your TableB and populate [Current_City] and [Birth_City] with nulls, but make sure [emp] is there and it has all the employees you intend to modify.

Then run this SQL modified to fit your database / schema / table names / etc:

```
update TableB
set Current_City = (select City
                    from TableA
                    where TableA.City_Type ='Z'
                    and TableA.emp = TableB.emp),
Birth_City = (select City
              from TableA
              where TableA.City_Type ='Y'
              and TableA.emp = TableB.emp)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the PIVOT transformation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but could you elaborate? I have searched for it, but couldn't really see how it would help me in this case.

Comment: Hmm, it seems the transformation can only work with numeric values, so it won't help in your case.   Instead you should do the PIVOT using SQL your Source query.